# iOS iVar named "Size" syntax error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Take this code :

```
@interface SomeClass:NSObject
{
@private
  NSString* Size;
}

@property NSString* Size;

@end

--------------------------

@implementation SomeClass
@synthesize Size;

- (void) something
{
  Size = @"syntax error : Expected identifier or '(' ";
  self.Size = @"works ok";
}

@end
```

Why is this a syntax error? Is "Size" a reserved word or already defined in NSSObject ?
I'm getting the error on two separate projects...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Size is a type:

```
typedef long                            Size;
```

Dont use it, and you should follow the Objective-C conventions, which are to name the properties with lowerCase.

Answer (score 2):

Did you option-Click or cmd+Click on Size (not self.Size)?
X Code should tell you that it is declared in MacTypes.h as `typedef long                            Size;`

Answer (score 1):

This is in MacTypes.h

```
typedef long Size;
```

It will cause a build error, I tested it in my own code.

Use objective C naming standards and you wont hit the conflict.

```
NSString *size;
```